# Why setting max-width: 100% of an image effectively set the maximum to its original width?

Tags: css, image, responsive

I know that to make an image responsive but not scaled up beyond its original size, all we have to do is setting max-width: 100%. But I am not sure why that setting works because literally it just tell the browser the image cannot exceed the width of the parent container, instead of the original image size. Could anyone please explain the reasons behind?

Comment: For those who have the same confusion as me (a beginner), I rephrase the answer hoping that it is clearer: by default (i.e. without additional style settings) the browser would display the image in its original size. So it is not the setting (max-width: 100%) that makes the image appear no more than its original size. The setting just shrink it, in case the container is not big enough to show it in original size, thus achieving a responsive effect in small screens (but not in large screens that responsiveness would distort the image quality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a 1000px wide image in a 400px wide div. max-width 100% prevents the image from exceeding the size of the div.

Comment: Thank for your reply.  But you did not get my point. I ask why setting max-width:100% prevents the image from exceeding the original size of the image, rather than the div size.

Comment: It doesn’t prevent it from exceeding the natural size of the image. The browser, by default, will render it at its natural size. If that same 1000px is in a 1600px div it will render at 1000px because that’s the size it naturally wants to be.

Comment: Can I say this: with max-width 100%, the browser tries to show the image in its natural size as long as the the display size is within the container width. In case the natural size is beyond the current container width, the browser will shrink the image to fit within the container width as stipulated by max-width 100%.